# Comparing two tables and finding mismatches

Tags: sql, mysql

ive got two sql tables and i want to comepare them against eachother to find the ones that dont match.

i have something that works but for some reason missed out two records?

table flag_content contains:
- userid
- content_id

table topfive_order contains
- nid
- uid

i wish to find all records which topfive_order.nid doesnt exists in flag_content.content_id

my current query is:

```
select * from flag_content left join topfive_order topfive_order ON flag_content.content_id = topfive_order.nid WHERE topfive_order.nid is null
```

any tips or advice much welcome. im not too sure what im doing with left join.. so i assume that the couple of records which slip the net has something to do with that.

Comment: The query seems correct. The two records you are missing, are they in the topfive_order table?

Answer (score 1):

Turn the join around

```
SELECT *
FROM topfive_order topfive_order left join flag_content 
  ON flag_content.content_id = topfive_order.nid 
WHERE flag_content.content_id IS NULL
```

To find rows from the `topfive_order` table that do not exist in the `flag_content` table, you need to put the `topfive_order` at the LEFT of the `LEFT JOIN`.

For more on various join types, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)